# Shopify Gift Cards API

Tags: api, shopify

I would like to know if there is a possibility to create **giftcards** like on the API Shopify :
https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-07/mutations/giftCardCreate#examples-Create_a_gift_card_with_a_custom_code_that_expires_on_a_specific_date
**Without having to switch to Shopify plus.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you explore this a little further, you may find that Shopify opened up Giftcards to other plans, as a **gift** during the pandemic, but they probably just did not update the docs to reflect that. In other words, if you take a few seconds to try out a mutation on a non-Plus store, and it works, then you are good to go. If it still comes back with a message that only Plus stores have it, then that is bad. But IIRC, they did gift it to everyone.